# How is coalesce function used in left side of a where clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query which i want to optimize

```
                SELECT DISTINCT
                  ues.user_id,
                  ues.user_type,
                  ues.owner
                FROM user_entitled_service ues
                LEFT JOIN user_resource_group urg
                    ON urg.org_id = ues.org_id AND urg.user_id = ues.user_id AND urg.service = ues.service
                INNER JOIN user_assignment ua
                    ON ua.org_id = ues.org_id AND ua.user_id = ues.user_id AND ua.service = ues.service
                WHERE ues.org_id = :orgId AND ues.service = CAST(:service AS service)
                    AND COALESCE(urg.resource_group_id, '') = :resourceGroupId
                    AND NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT org_id, user_id, service, cluster_id
                        FROM user_discover_state
                        WHERE status = '${UserDiscoverStatus.found}'
                          AND org_id = ues.org_id AND user_id = ues.user_id AND service = ues.service)
```

I want to be able to use index on resource_group_id but since it uses coalesce function , cant do there as it wouldnt use index. What I am not clear about is why coalesce is used in the left side , most queries that I have seen use it on the right side , which makes more sense, since we are matching a column (key) to a value, how does it work when used in right side? And can we use it for index ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your exact data and query logic, I can't comment directly on the exact use of `COALESCE`.  What I *can* do is to rewrite the logic such that it becomes sargable (i.e. such that an index can be used):

```
AND COALESCE(urg.resource_group_id, '') = :resourceGroupId
```

this becomes:

```
AND urg.resource_group_id = :resourceGroupId OR
    urg.resource_group_id IS NULL AND :resourceGroupId = ''
```

Comment: So the resourceGroupId is coming in through the function parameter which executes this query, but if we do ```urg.resource_group_id = :resourceGroupId``` does it not also include the cases where resourceGroupId = ' ' ?

Comment: Yes...but that's not your current `COALSECE` logic, right?  Your logic says that when the column is null, the param is empty string.

Comment: ok... so would it be better if we used ```(urg.resource_group_id IS NOT NULL AND urg.resource_group_id = :resourceGroupId ) OR
    (urg.resource_group_id IS NULL AND :resourceGroupId = ' ')``` since i believe if we have a nullable column and we want to use index we need to ensure not null by specifying IS NOT NULL

Comment: or if we can have an index for COALESCE(resource_group_id, " ")

Comment: I don't get your comments.  In any case, the version I gave does not use any function in the condition, and should be, in theory, candidate for an index.